# Pyspark merge based on whether value is in a list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two Spark dataframes (I'm using python), say A and B. A contains a column with a string (say "Name"), whereas B contains a column with a list of strings (say "NamesList"). What I would like to do is merge A and B based on whether A.Name is contained in B.NamesList.

So to give you an example, A could be

```
+---+------+
| Id|  Name|
+---+------+
|  1|George|
|  2| Sarah|
+---+------+
```

B could be

```
+---+--------------------+
|Id2|           NamesList|
+---+--------------------+
|  6| [Bob, Alice, Sarah]|
|  7|[Thomas, Bob, Alice]|
+---+--------------------+
```

And I would like the result to be

```
+---+---+-----+-------------------+
| Id|Id2| Name|          NamesList|
+---+---+-----+-------------------+
|  2|  6|Sarah|[Bob, Alice, Sarah]|
+---+---+-----+-------------------+
```

Any ideas how to do this in an efficient way?

Comment: how big are your dataframes ?

Comment: They have around 600K entries.